# How do I make a div disappear when any other div is targeted?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been using CSS tabs to make one page, in which you can navigate through different content using `:target`. I want to find a way to make it so that one div shows as the home page, without anything being clicked, and it disappears when a div is targeted. I don't want it to be an onclick event, since I want it to be invisible from the other content if you're coming from a link with the targeted ID.

I feel like my best example of what I mean is similar to how carrds work, with the first control being visible when the website loads, but disappearing if there's a different one targeted? I know that for that, it's the same div, but I'm hoping for a simpler solution than whatever carrd has going on. [Example](https://example-of-what-i-want.carrd.co)

So, this would all be in one HTML document, but I basically want a home page to appear if there's no div targeted, and it goes away if you target a div.

Ideally, in the url, `index.html` would show the home div, `index.html#div01` would make that home div disappear, and instead show a different div with the same content, and `index.html#div02` would have completely different content, but I don't know how to get that first part to work. I've been playing around with pseudo-classes and whatever potential solutions I could find online, but nothing's worked quite the way I want it to. Simplifying what I have by removing the unhelpful JavaScript and extra styling, this is what I'm currently sitting with.

Example of what I tried

```css
.tabcontent {
  display: none
}

.tabcontent:target {
  display: block
}

.home {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#div01"><button>Div 01</button></a>
  <a href="#div02"><button>Div 02</button></a>
</div>
<div class="home tabcontent">
  <p>So this is the home page...</p>
</div>
<div id="div01" class="tabcontent">
  <p>So this is the home page...</p>
</div>
<div id="div02" class="tabcontent">
  <p>And this is something different!</p>
</div>
```

While I'd like to avoid jQuery if possible, I'll try out anything!

Comment: You tagged this `javascript`, but it seems like you're trying to do this *without* JavaScript. Which is it? Are you willing to accept a JS solution?

Comment: There may not be a pure CSS way to make `.home` visible only if none of the other `.tabcontent` are targeted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in pure CSS by leveraging [:not()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) and [:has()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has).

```
  body:not(body:has(.tabcontent:target)) .home {
    display: block;
  }
```

They have [good support in modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/css-has) (with the notable exception of Firefox) but you might need a fallback for old browsers. In this example we check if the browser [@supports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports) relational pseudo classes and if not apply some Javascript instead.

```js
//optional JS fallback for if :has is not supported.
try {
    document.querySelector(":not(:has(+ *))");
} catch (error) {
    //not suppoted. do something else
    document.querySelector("a[href='#div01']").click();//maybe manually trigger the click
}
```

```css
.tabcontent {
  display: none
}

.tabcontent:target {
  display: block
}

@supports selector(:not(:has(+ *))) {
  body:not(body:has(.tabcontent:target)) .home {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#div01"><button>Div 01</button></a>
  <a href="#div02"><button>Div 02</button></a>
</div>
<div id="div01" class="home tabcontent">
  <p>So this is the home page...</p>
</div>
<div id="div02" class="tabcontent">
  <p>And this is something different!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will see that this way...

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', evt =>
  {
  let hashValues = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[name="pageSelector"]')].map(elm=>`#${elm.id}` );

  if ( hashValues.includes( window.location.hash ) )
    {
    document.querySelector(window.location.hash).checked = true;
    }
  document.querySelectorAll('input[name="pageSelector"]').forEach( elmR => 
    {
    elmR.onchange =_=>
      {
      window.location.hash = elmR.id;
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
html {
  font-family     : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size       : 16px;
  }
input[name="pageSelector"]             ,
#div00:checked ~ section:not(#part_00) ,
#div01:checked ~ section:not(#part_01) ,
#div02:checked ~ section:not(#part_02) { 
  display : none; 
  }
input[name="pageSelector"] + label { 
  display       : inline-block;
  width         : 8em;
  border        : 1px solid darkgray;
  background    : aliceblue;
  text-align    : center;
  padding       : .3em 0 .4em 0;
  border-radius : .2em;
  margin: .2em;
  }
input[name="pageSelector"]:checked + label {   
  background    : lightblue;
  }
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="pageSelector" id="div00" checked value="" ><label for="div00">  home page   </label>
<input type="radio" name="pageSelector" id="div01"         value="" ><label for="div01">  see page 01 </label>
<input type="radio" name="pageSelector" id="div02"         value="" ><label for="div02">  see page 02 </label>



<section id="part_00">
  <p>So this is the home page...</p>
</section>
<section id="part_01">
  <p>So this is the page 01...</p>
</section>
<section id="part_02">
  <p>So this is the page 02...</p>
</section>
```